# Как получить полное имя директории, если знаешь, с чего оно начинается?

Tags: bash

Суть такова: в рабочей директории есть каталог, имя которого соответствует паттерну `firmware*`. Гарантируется, что он там такой один. Задача - сохранить его имя в переменную. Каталог через scp потом отправляется на устройство и через ssh мы должны запустить скрипт из этого каталога, для этого и сохраняем имя (`firmware*` не подойдет - там таких много).

Мои попытки решить:

1. `` dir=`ls firmware*` ``

Просто выводит содержимое директории. Если их сделать несколько, то всех по очереди. Не подходит.

2. `` dir=`find -maxdepth 1 -name firmware*` ``

Выдает `./firmware-11.07.2019-15:16:17`. Этот вариант работает, поэтому я пока на нем остановился. Я новичок в shell-скриптах, и возможно, что решил неоптимальным способом, поэтому мне интересно, как можно сделать это правильнее?

Comment: По первому решению - вы сделали "почти". `man ls`, пролистать до опции `-d`, вот что там: `list directories themselves, not their contents`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash, когда видит звездочку, сам подставляет все то, что найдет в текущем каталоге

поэтому достаточно

```
dir=`echo firmware*`
# либо
dir=`ls -d firmware*`
echo "$dir"
```

Comment: Это проще, чем мой вариант. Не знаю, как скрипт поведет себя, если в имени файла будут пробелы, но мне повезло, что их там нет.

Comment: @trollingchar `dir=“$(ls -1d “firmware*”)“`. С `find`, конечно, вариант самый правильный.